# How to avoid fade-out on scaled CCSprite without cancelling anti-aliasing?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have 3 sprites. Left edge, right edge, and repeating center which has 1 pixel width but is scaled up. The problem is that the scaled sprite fades out the farther away it is from the center:

[image]

I've tried using CCTexture's setAliasTexParameters but the result doesn't look good: [image]

How do I get the antialiased looks in the first picture but without the fade out problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on the sprite:

```
// These parameters set the texture properties: 
// minifying filter - linear interpolation, 
// magnification filter - linear interpolation, 
// texture repeat in S direction, 
// texture repeat in T direction (*)
ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
[sprite.texture setTexParams:&params];

// This explicitly sets the contentSize of the sprite to (10, 200), 
// but also sets the "window to the texture" to this rectangle:  
[sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 200)];
```

You have to tweak these settings, but hope you get it.
You don't have to scale the sprite.

(*) For S and T check this: [Difference between U V and S T texture coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568390/difference-between-u-v-and-s-t-texture-coordinates)